# All the threads do the same thing. cpp

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector

I'm a beginner in CPP and we have reached in class the subject of threading.
I'm trying to play with it a bit and it seem not to work as I want it.

I want each thread to push the number of j inside the vector and then print the vector to the console.

It seems that all of them print the value '10' the last value that j holds after the end of the loop.

```
vector<int> foo(int x) {
    vector<int> a;
    a.push_back(x);
    return a;
}

void print(vector<int> vec) {
    for (int i = 0; i<int(vec.size()); i++)
        cout << vec[i] <<endl;
}

void foo2(int x) {
    vector<int> b;
    thread thr([&] {b = foo(x); });
    thr.join();
    mtx1.lock();
    print(b);
    mtx1.unlock();
}

int main() {
    vector<thread> th;
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        th.emplace_back(([&] {foo2(j); }));
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        th[j].join();
}
```

NOTE: I want that the vector of threads will go inside the function call a new thread that will push the number into the vector and then print.

The output I get is:

```
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
```

I'm aiming for:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: print() has no race condition, it is useless to lock or unlock. You will need a different synchronization method in order to print `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` and not a different  permutation

Comment: What should I use if not mutex?

Comment: I'd have an array where each thread writes its result to. Each writes to a specific cell so there's no race condition. After all is done I'd print it.

Comment: I am not losing the purpose of parallelising when I do that?
I thought I can lock the << operator somehow and let each type but I see that I cant really know who gets to the operator first.

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    th.emplace_back(([&] {foo2(j); }));
```

The lambda captures `j` by reference (that's what `[&]` means, after all), the lambda gets used to construct a new `std::thread`, and this `for` loop ***immediately*** iterates, incrementing `j`.

But, if you were paying close attention, you would've noticed that `j` is captured by reference, and C++ gives you no guarantees, whatsoever, that the new thread  will read the value of `j`, and call `foo2()`, before the `for` loop in the parent thread iterates and increments `j`.

What happens here is that the for loop runs quickly enough so that it finishes before all the threads actually start running on their own, and all they see is the last value of `j` (and not even that, since this specific `j` goes out of scope and gets destroyed when this `for` loop terminates, because it's declared local to the `for` loop, which technically means that accessing `j` [makes demons fly out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)).

Solution: capture `j` by value (that would be `[=]` or `[j]`), not reference.

P.S. And even after you do that, you have no guarantees whatsoever that all the values from 0 to 9 will be printed in order. It all depends upon the threads executing `std::cout << ...` in the specific order, which, again, you have absolutely no guarantees about which thread will reach that statement in relationship to all other threads.

Comment: Thank you very much! What if I want to pass some by reference and some by value ?

Comment: You are very welcome, and always be on the lookout for demons flying out your nose when working with threads, which are very prone to it. You can pass anything by reference or value, as long as you fully understand what's going on and make arrangements, using mutexes and condition variables, than any reference gets used in the new thread before the referenced object gets destroyed in the parent thread.

Comment: @TalVol Re, "What if I want to pass some by reference and some by value?" If that's what you want your code to do, then write your code to do that. Just be sure that you understand what you are doing, and why you are doing it.